# how can I use builtin function in my python divisor code?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, types, built-in-types

I'm getting error on the line with (if counter > max_count:). It says not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'. I can't underestand what is the problem!

```
def divisors(num):
    counter=1
    for i in range(1,num):
        x = num%i
        if x==0:
            counter+=1
    return counter

max_count= 0
Number=0
for i in range(3):
    number = int(input('\nEnter the Number : '))
    counter=divisors(number)

    if counter > max_count:
        max_count=counter
        Number=number

    elif counter==max_count:
        max_count=max

        if number>Number:
            Number=number    
    

print('\n',Number,max_count)
```

Comment: It depends on the numbers entered. When I ran it I didn't get that error. In any event, the problem is in the line `max_count=max`. Here you are assigning the function `max` to the variable `max_count`. You probably wanted to assign the max of something, not the function `max` itself. `max` by itself doesn't make sense in this context but something like `max(nums)` would.

Comment: @JohnColeman Exactly. I just found out that. I have to use colorizing code extension which helps me to understand if I'm assigning a wrong variable or function etc. Big Thanks! BTW it should be counter instead of max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on **max** function, or just missed to defines the scope.

Current: `max`

Expected: `max([value_a, value_b])`, or just nothing. This depends on your purpose.

Using only "max" will return `<built-in function max>` has value of max_count when both equal.

Comment: Yes, I got this. I meant counter instead of max!